# Is this a good approach for using lock tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'd like to use a lock table for pessimistic offline locking to prevent the case when multiple users work on one work item. I'm using a lock table for storing the active locks and two stored procedures for locking and unlocking.

My lock table's structure is the following: CaseId (PK) | UserId | LockValidTo.

For locking and unlocking I wrote two stored procedures, one for locking and one for unlocking.

This is my stored procedure for locking:

```
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO scs.dbo.caselocks VALUES (@caseId, @agentId, dateadd(n, @lockTime, getdate()) )
        SELECT 0
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT 1
    END CATCH
END
```

And this is for removing locks:

```
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        DELETE FROM scs.dbo.caselocks
        WHERE caseid = @caseid
        SELECT 0
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT 1
    END CATCH
END
```

My question is that, is this a right approach for the handling locks? (Sorry if this should have been posted to Code Review instead of SO.)

Comment: I think this approach will work.  Making `CaseId` the PK in your `caselocks` table will prevent any race conditions.  How often to you plan on locking and unlocking?  Have you considered the performance of this approach?

Comment: what's wrong with standard SQL inherent locking?  The problem with this approach is, what happens if the program breaks or stops or is killed or whatever before it unlocks the record?

Comment: Locks will be removed when the user finishes their work on the item he or she edited. (And a scheduled job will clean up locks in case when the application crashes/etc.) Regarding to performance, I don't really know how would this perform. Is there a more 'efficient' way to this?

Answer (score 1):

For the delete SP, will you allow any agent to delete the lock?  Also, why are you returning a ResultSet from the SP with "SELECT"?  You could just use the RETURN statement.

I see that you are using the getdate() function to persist a time in the local time zone.  This is often a cause of issues when you deal with multiple time zones, switches to/from Daylight Savings Time, etc.  The best practice is to always use UTC times whenever you persist a date/time and only convert to local time when the time is displayed to a user.

Comment: Agents cannot delete locks, locking and unlocking is managed by the application when an agent tries to open a work item in edit mode. Thanks for the UTC usage & return suggestions.